# MySQL - Select date and time for a max value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a meteorological database and I want to retrieve date and time when a maximum value of the temperature during the day is reached.

I can get the maximum value of the temperature, but the date and time returned are for the first entry for that date.

To be more explicit:

```
DATE(DateTime)|DateTime           |TempOutCur
    2017-11-19|2017-11-19 00:01:19|6.7
    2017-11-19|2017-11-19 00:06:22|6.7
    2017-11-19|2017-11-19 00:11:25|6.7
    2017-11-19|2017-11-19 00:16:28|6.7
    ................
    2017-11-19|2017-11-19 10:50:32|10.3 (this is max of the day)
    ................
```

The query

```
SELECT DATE(DateTime), DateTime, MAX(TempOutCur) 
FROM meteo_database GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)
```

is returning:

```
DATE(DateTime)|DateTime           |MAX(TempOutCur)
    2017-11-19|2017-11-19 00:01:19|10.3
```

As you can see date and time returned are not correct.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question*?  The value of `DateTime` returned by that query is indeterminate; it's a value from one of the rows in the collapsed "group", but it could be any row in that group. A  MySQL-specific extension allows the query to execute (unless ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is included in sql_mode). Other databases would throw an error because of the non-aggregate (`DateTime`) in the SELECT list but not in the GROUP BY.  The resultset appears to conform to the MySQL specification, as documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a join with a subquery  with the  max temp

```
select DATE(m.DateTime), m.DateTime , m.TempOutCur
from meteo_database m
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT DATE(DateTime) my_date, MAX(TempOutCur) max_temp
    FROM meteo_database 
    GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)
) T on T.my_date = DATE(m.DateTime) AND T.max_temp = m.TempOutCur
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to specify the aggregate in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT DATE(DateTime), DateTime, TempOutCur
FROM meteo_database
WHERE TempOutCur = (SELECT MAX(TempOutCur) FROM meteo_database)
```